# Which is the minimum iOS version and iPhone version require to be able to use a virtual background in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: ios, ms-office

Which is the minimum iOS version and iPhone version required to be able to use a virtual background in Microsoft Teams? I see on https://www.windowscentral.com/teams-ios-now-supports-custom-background-images?amp that the virtual background option is available on iOS but wonder what the phone requirements are.

Comment: Is this a hypothetical question or are you trying to solve a practical problem?

Comment: @nohillside a real problem. I want the feature but my currently Android phone It doesn't have it so I'd like to buy an iPhone to have the feature. I'm doing over a thousand of meetings on Microsoft teams every year.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 4):

From https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/hardware-requirements-for-the-teams-app

> Support is limited to the two most recent major versions of iOS. For example, when a new, major version of iOS is released, the iOS requirement is the new version and the most recent versions that preceded it. The optional Blur my background video effect on iOS requires an operating system of iOS 12 or later, compatible with the following devices: iPhone 7 or later, iPad 2018 (6th generation) or later, and the iPod touch 2019 (7th generation).

I also found a page announcing that support for iOS 13 will end this month. But iPhones 7 and later will run iOS 14 (and 15) so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, do you know whether the Blur my background video feature has the same requirements as the add virtual background feature?

Comment: Blur background !=  add virtual background. Not that easy to find. I'll keep looking around.